# How to omit user@location from Unix shell prompt?

Tags: unix, ps1

I am using Unix and I login in my account.

Then my command line looks like this:

```
[username@somestupidfolder]$
```

How can I hide this information so I can get clean `$` as cursor.

Basically:

`[username@somestupidfolder]$` to `$`

Comment: Note that it is conventional to leave a space after the `$` in the prompt.  Both the answers do that for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run

```
PS1="$ "
```

from the terminal. If you want this to persist every time you launch a new terminal, you will need to add this change to your `.bash_rc`. `PS1` should already be defined there (and giving you the present format you see).

Answer (score 3):

It depends from the `shell` you are using

for `bash` shell:
`PS1="$ "`
to make it stable for each new shell you will  write it in `.bash_rc` or in `.profile`
(or in `.bash_profile`).

for `csh` or `tcsh`
`set prompt="$ "`
to make it stable for each new shell you will  write it in  `.cshrc` or `.tcshrc` (if it is a `tcsh` shell)

for a `zsh`

`PROMPT='$ '`
to make it stable for each new shell you will  write it in  `.zshrc`

**Bonus**: If you are in `bash` and you want a minimalist prompt with a nice feature you can try

```
PS1="\`if [ \$? = 0 ]; then echo -e '\[\e[01;32m\]$'; else echo -e '\[\e[01;31m\]$'; fi\` \[\e[0m\]"
```

You will have a green `$` if the last command was finished without error, or red otherwise.

Comment: I didn't know in which shell you work... there's a little **bonus**. Give it a check if it follows what you where searching for. :)

Comment: nice feature, but it gives me red if I close file with [CTRL]+[Z]